# probability for socks pairs

Tags: combinatorics

Anna will give all her socks to her five poor aunts. She finds out that she has socks in k different colours. Moreover she has n pairs of each colour(n > 4). In how many ways can this be done if she for keeping the family peace gives each aunt at least one pair of each colour.

can anyone help me with the solution

Answer (score 2):

Start by distributing the "one pair of each colour" to each of the aunts. We're then left to distribute $n-5$ pairs of each colour among the aunts with *no* additional conditions. This can be done for each colour separately, and the number of ways for each colour can then be multiplied together.

Looking at one colour only, distributing $n-5$ indistinguishable pairs of socks among 5 aunts is a straightforward [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem with $\binom{n-1}{n-5}$ different solutions.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: No -- there are $n-5$ stars and $4$ bars, totaling $n-1$ objects. The lower number can be either $n-5$ (chose where the stars are) or $4$ (choose where the bars are), depending on temperament.

Comment: Yes sorry, I realized after posting the comment, thanks!